# How can I set a Route53 record as an alias for EKS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I set an EKS cluster using Terraform. I try to set Route53 record to map my domain name, to the load balancer of my cluster.

I set my EKS cluster:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name     = "${var.project}-cluster"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version  = "1.24"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = flatten([aws_subnet.public[*].id, aws_subnet.private[*].id])
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = true
    public_access_cidrs     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-cluster",
    }
  )

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster_AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
  ]
}
```

And I have created the following k8s service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: backend-service
spec:
    selector:
        app: dashboard-backend
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: '$PORT'
          targetPort: '$PORT'
```

**As far as I know, once I deploy a k8s service, AWS automatically generates an ALB resource for my service.** So, I set this route53 sources:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name = var.domain_name

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-Route53-zone",
    }
  )
}

data "kubernetes_service" "backend" {
  metadata {
    name = "backend-service"
  }
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "backend_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "www.api"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"

  alias {
    name                   = data.kubernetes_service.backend.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
    zone_id                = ??????
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

I did get the load balancer host name using `data.kubernetes_service.backend.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname`, but how can I get its zone ID to use in `zone_id` key?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ELB-hosted Zone Id using the data source [`aws_elb_hosted_zone_id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/elb_hosted_zone_id), as it only depends on the region where you created this ELB. Technically you can hardcode this value also because these are static values on a regional basis.

Official AWS Documentation on [Elastic Load Balancing endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html)

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name = var.domain_name

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-Route53-zone",
    }
  )
}

data "kubernetes_service" "backend" {
  metadata {
    name = "backend-service"
  }
}

## Add data source ## 
data "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" "this" {}
### This will use your aws provider-level region config otherwise mention explicitly.

resource "aws_route53_record" "backend_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "www.api"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"

  alias {
    name                   = data.kubernetes_service.backend.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
    zone_id                = data.aws_elb_hosted_zone_id.this.id ## Updated ##
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Out of your question scope, even though hopefully this may work but I would also suggest you look into [external-dns](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/integrations/external_dns/) for managing DNS with EKS.

Comment: What about a case where I deploy 2 services? Let's they are both configured as the same, except for the `metadata.name` of course. How should I add this `data "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" "this" {} ` now to configure both?

Comment: if the alb deployed for them is in same region then the syntax remain the same  because zone_id in alias block is a static value which only depends on the region where lb is deployed, if my answer had helped please accept and upvote the answer thanks

Comment: So as you can see in the Q I configured `data "kubernetes_service" "backend"` and I get an error when running `terraform plan`:
```data.kubernetes_service.backend: Reading...

Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/backend-service": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused``` Do you have an idea about this issue, what's wrong?

Comment: Could you please open another question for this, unfortunately, this is another thing than the question statement "How can I set a Route53 record as an alias for EKS load balancer?"  hint: might be Kubernetes provider configuration.